# how to tell IntelliJ IDEA to search for a contiguous string?

Tags: intellij-idea

I feel stupid asking this but I can't find the answer in the Help nor on google. The very useful feature of IDEA of treating the search term (in Navigate to Symbol - double-shift) as an abbreviation, which helps finding long names like `ResponseBuilder` by typing `resbu` can be very unhelpful, e.g. when searching for `setex` method it finds all kind of strings like **Set**Timeout**Ex**pired. Can it be disabled? Checkmarking "Words" is a partial solution, as I may be searching for a contiguous string yet not a full word.

Comment: Which search feature exactly do you mean? The "Find in Path" feature does not treat search terms as abbreviations.

Comment: @yole correct, I'm talking about symbol search

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean, when you talk about "search"?

- When doing a "Find" or "Find in Path", IDEA is *always* searching for a contiguous string.
- When doing a Go to Class/File/Symbol/Action IDEA is *always* doing the "word-part" search. There is no checkmark for "Words" here AFAICS.

A small tip that sometimes helps: If you do a "Go to Class/File/Symbol/Action", then you can enter a space " " after the last character to make IDEA search classes etc. that end with the search term, for example "setex " would not find "SetTimeoutExpired", but "setexpired " would find it, but would skip "SetTimeExpiredToFalse".

Comment: that's correct, I was talking about double shift / symbol. I'll correct